# Custom image slider bug: using clearInterval to stop auto advance does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I am working on a custom image carousel, with jQuery and CSS. The aim is to make it really *lightweight* but with (just) enough features.

The script has an `auto` feature that I want to be *stopped if the user clicks a bullet*. I am using `clearInterval` for this purpose. Here is the code:

```js
var $elm = $('.slider'),
  $slidesContainer = $elm.find('.slider-container'),
  slides = $slidesContainer.children('a'),
  slidesCount = slides.length,
  slideHeight = $(slides[0]).find('img').outerHeight(false),
  animationspeed = 300,
  animationInterval = 4000;

// Set (initial) z-index for each slide
var setZindex = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < slidesCount; i++) {
    $(slides[i]).css('z-index', slidesCount - i);
  }
};
setZindex();

var displayImageBeforeClick = null;

var setActiveSlide = function() {
  $(slides).removeClass('active');
  $(slides[activeIdx]).addClass('active');
};

var advanceFunc = function() {
  if ($('.slider-nav li.activeSlide').index() + 1 != $('.slider-nav li').length) {
    $('.slider-nav li.activeSlide').next().find('a').trigger('click');
  } else {
    $('.slider-nav li:first').find('a').trigger('click');
  }
}

var autoAdvance = function() {
  setInterval(advanceFunc, animationInterval);
};

//Set slide height
$(slides).css('height', slideHeight);

// Append bullets
for (var i = 0; i < slidesCount; i++) {
  var bullets = '<li><a href="#">' + i + '</a></li>';
  if (i == 0) {
    // active bullet
    var bullets = '<li class="activeSlide"><a href="#">' + i + '</a></li>';
    // active slide
    $(slides[0]).addClass('active');
  }
  $('.slider-nav').append(bullets);
};

var slideUpDown = function() {
  // set top property for all the slides
  $(slides).not(displayImageBeforeClick).css('top', slideHeight);
  // then animate to the next slide
  $(slides[activeIdx]).animate({
    'top': 0
  }, animationspeed);

  $(displayImageBeforeClick).animate({
    'top': "-100%"
  }, animationspeed);
};

autoAdvance();

$('.slider-nav a').on('click', function(event) {
  displayImageBeforeClick = $(".slider-container .active");
  activeIdx = $(this).text();
  if ($(slides[activeIdx]).hasClass("active")) {
    return false;
  }
  $('.slider-nav a').closest('li').removeClass('activeSlide');
  $(this).closest('li').addClass('activeSlide');
  
  // Stop autoadvance if user clicks bullet
  if (event.originalEvent !== undefined) {
    clearInterval(autoAdvance);
  }

  setActiveSlide();
  slideUpDown();
});
```

```css
body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider .slider-nav {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 2px;
  z-index: 30;
}

.slider .slider-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 0 1px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

.slider .slider-nav a {
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  line-height: 3px;
}

.slider .slider-nav li.activeSlide {
  background: #fff;
}

.slider .slider-nav li.activeSlide a {
  display: none;
}

.slider .slider-container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.slider .slider-container a {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.slider .slider-container img {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.0/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="slider slider-homepage">
    <ul class="slider-nav"></ul>
    <div class="slider-container">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/300/?gravity=east" alt="">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/300/?gravity=south" alt="">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/300/?gravity=north" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**The problem**: even though the console shows no error(s), the auto advance does not stop. I have been trying for hours now to figure out the problem, without success.

Comment: Try setting autoAdvance equal to the setInterval instead of a function that executes the interval. That should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set your variable autoAdvance equal to the setInterval instead of a function that executes the interval. Then your clearInterval will work.

ex: `var autoAdvance = setInterval(advanceFunc, animationInterval);`

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix the problem (with the help of tnyN), like this:

1) I  replaced

```
var autoAdvance = function() {
  setInterval(advanceFunc, animationInterval);
};
```

with `var autoAdvance = setInterval(advanceFunc, animationInterval);`

2) Got rid of `autoAdvance();`

Here is the full working code:

```js
var $elm = $('.slider'),
  $slidesContainer = $elm.find('.slider-container'),
  slides = $slidesContainer.children('a'),
  slidesCount = slides.length,
  slideHeight = $(slides[0]).find('img').outerHeight(false),
  animationspeed = 300,
  animationInterval = 4000;

// Set (initial) z-index for each slide
var setZindex = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < slidesCount; i++) {
    $(slides[i]).css('z-index', slidesCount - i);
  }
};
setZindex();

var displayImageBeforeClick = null;

var setActiveSlide = function() {
  $(slides).removeClass('active');
  $(slides[activeIdx]).addClass('active');
};

var advanceFunc = function() {
  if ($('.slider-nav li.activeSlide').index() + 1 != $('.slider-nav li').length) {
    $('.slider-nav li.activeSlide').next().find('a').trigger('click');
  } else {
    $('.slider-nav li:first').find('a').trigger('click');
  }
}

var autoAdvance = setInterval(advanceFunc, animationInterval);

//Set slide height
$(slides).css('height', slideHeight);

// Append bullets
for (var i = 0; i < slidesCount; i++) {
  var bullets = '<li><a href="#">' + i + '</a></li>';
  if (i == 0) {
    // active bullet
    var bullets = '<li class="activeSlide"><a href="#">' + i + '</a></li>';
    // active slide
    $(slides[0]).addClass('active');
  }
  $('.slider-nav').append(bullets);
};

var slideUpDown = function() {
  // set top property for all the slides
  $(slides).not(displayImageBeforeClick).css('top', slideHeight);
  // then animate to the next slide
  $(slides[activeIdx]).animate({
    'top': 0
  }, animationspeed);

  $(displayImageBeforeClick).animate({
    'top': "-100%"
  }, animationspeed);
};

$('.slider-nav a').on('click', function(event) {
  displayImageBeforeClick = $(".slider-container .active");
  activeIdx = $(this).text();
  if ($(slides[activeIdx]).hasClass("active")) {
    return false;
  }
  $('.slider-nav a').closest('li').removeClass('activeSlide');
  $(this).closest('li').addClass('activeSlide');
  
  // Stop autoadvance if user clicks bullet
  if (event.originalEvent !== undefined) {
    clearInterval(autoAdvance);
  }

  setActiveSlide();
  slideUpDown();
});
```

```css
body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider .slider-nav {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 2px;
  z-index: 30;
}

.slider .slider-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 0 1px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

.slider .slider-nav a {
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  line-height: 3px;
}

.slider .slider-nav li.activeSlide {
  background: #fff;
}

.slider .slider-nav li.activeSlide a {
  display: none;
}

.slider .slider-container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.slider .slider-container a {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.slider .slider-container img {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.0/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="slider slider-homepage">
    <ul class="slider-nav"></ul>
    <div class="slider-container">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/300/?gravity=east" alt="">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/300/?gravity=south" alt="">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/300/?gravity=north" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```